# How to stop SRM Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, arch-linux, secure-erase

I'm using SRM to delete one file. Already 12 hours srm is working for deleting a 7GB file and it have only 3 stars ***

Is there a way to stop it or to pause so I do that another day.

Comment: `srm` does 38 passes by default, so it will write 228GB to delete the file.  It will have already overwritten the file several times by now.  You could just control-c it and do a less secure pass later - in accumulation it can amount to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. How I can check the speed of overwriting and approximate time ?

Comment: You can pause any program by sending it a STOP signal (it does not mean terminate), and resume with a CONT signal. You can do this with `kill` options or from Task Monitor. The suspended state will not be resumed after a reboot, but sleep or hibernate is fine.

Answer (score 0):

#### A crash-course to killing command-line / text-mode programs

To elaborate on @AFH's comment, if "SRM" is a console (command-line interface) program, and you have run it from a terminal, just hit `Ctrl-z`, as this makes your terminal send the foreground process it manages that `SIGSTOP` signal and send it to the background. You can then "bring it back" by executing the `fg` shell command—it's a part of the so-called "job control" implemented by interactive shells and means bringing the backgrounded process to foreground (hence "fg") which includes sending the process the `SIGCONT` signal among other things.

Of course, to stop a process just, stop it. On Unix-y systems, including Linux-based OSes, this is done by sending the process one of special signals—usually `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT`. Hitting `Ctrl-c` in a terminal which runs a process makes that send the process the `SIGINT` signal. The `kill` program may be used to send arbitrary processes arbitrary signals.

The problem with using `kill` is that for most of its uses it requires
the user to know the so-called "PID" of the process to send the signal to.
PID is a **P**rocess **ID**entifier—an integer number ≥ 1 unique across
all the processes currently managed by the OS.

The shell's job control makes it easier as it has certain mnemonics to
refer to the processes it manages: if you background the currently active
process by hitting `Ctrl-z`, you can then use the `jobs` command
to see the list of processes managed by that shell.
For example, I've just suspended an instance of `mutt`
and run `jobs` after that; here's what I see:

```
~$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 mutt
```

Notice that `[1]+` bit.
The `1` is the job identifier assigned to that process by the shell.
The `+` is a "handle" to refer to the last backgrounded process.

So you can now use either `%1` or `%+` with the `kill` command
to refer to that process, like in

```
$ kill %1
```

or

```
$ kill %+
```

…and they will all send `SIGTERM` to that single backgrounded process.

That's how you can kill a misbehaving console program.

More on singals

Note that those `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` signals can be "handled"
by the process which received one of them.
This allows the process to perform certain cleanup actions before
quitting.

But sometimes a process might "hang" — say by executing an endless
loop on a CPU due to a programming bug or by being stuck by trying
to read/write from/to a file on some "dead" resource such as disconnected
network share.
In these cases delivering `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` won't typically
be able to "unwedge" the process.

To deal with such cases, there exist a special signal, `SIGQUIT`,
which has a well-known number assigned to it, "9".
Sending a process this signal merely makes the OS forcibly nuke the
process without it having any chance to intervene.
That's why you most probably saw that `kill -9 $pid` encantation
in some docs.

#### Other options

There are other options, of course.

First, there exist "user-friendly" programs such as `htop` which
present you with a searcheable list of running processes and allow you
to send any of them a sgnal of choice.

Graphical desktop environments—such as GNOME, XFCE, KDE and others—usually
provide a GUI app to do the same.

Second, there exist more "hacky" ways to deal with misbehaving
processes for the cases where those "task managers" are unavailable
or do not fit the bill for some reason.
Here are some of them in no particular order:

- The `xkill` utility (on Debian and its derivative it's in
  the `x11-utils` package), when run, shows you a diagonal cross-shaped
  cursor with which you ought to select any window by cicking on it,
  and `xkill` will forcibly disconnect the process which owns that window
  from the X server (the program which renders all your GUI).

  The effect of this action differs between processes,
  but if you `xkill` a terminal window it will send the `SIGHUP` signal
  to the processes it manages, and this usually makes them quit.
- The `pkill` utility (on Debian and its derivative it's in
  the `procps` package) can be used to send a signal to a set of processes
  whose name matches a certain string.

  So, if you want to kill an `srm` process you know is running
  on your system, you can run

  ```
   $ pkill -9 srm
  ```

to bring down all the processes named `srm` running on the system.

Answer (score -1):

The real answer is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/270556/how-many-passes-do-you-need-to-wipe-shred-your-files-to-make-them-not-undeletabl)

TL;DR with modern disks (and that includes anything that can hold a 7GB file), you don't really need to be that paranoid.

Since you only need to over write your file with zeros:

```
shred -n 0 -z trashed.dat
```

- where `-n 0` means 0 passes with random data (without that you get the default 3 passes with random data, but that's still overkill)
- `-z` one final pass with zeroes (the only one needed)

Given this, to efficiently finish your secure erase:

1. stop the current command
2. run the `shred` command above

(*bracing for sudden kharma drop...*)

Comment: The question wasn't "is this needed", but "how can I pause".  So this is not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: Yes, it is. Answer to the X part of an XY problem... Stop it, and use something else that will execute much faster.

Comment: Including that, and a solution would be an answer to the question, this is not.  Please [edit] and provide detail.